# Copula Invariance Principle

Tags: mathematical-statistics, multivariate-analysis, cumulative-distribution-function, copula, multivariate-distribution

I don't get why equation 7 is true, can someone explain me why? This is part of the proof of the invariance principle in copula theory. [image]

Comment: Welcome to CV, David. This is a direct consequence of the definition of a copula.  The $T_i$ are merely ways of using different numbers to express the same quantities; they don't actually do anything to the copula itself.  Perhaps some consideration of the [Probability Integral Transform](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Probability+Integral+Transform) will help make this clear.